# How can I return two variables in a constraint (scipy.minimize)?

Tags: python, scipy, constraints

Currently I am working on an optimization problem in python. Therefore, I am using scipy.minimize. The goal of my optimization problem is to maximize the profit. The profit is generated out of water. So water used for a certain goal, cannot be used for something else. In my current model, water can be used for agriculture of the production of hydropower. Of course, it is not possible to use more water than available. So one of the constraints is called a sustainability constraint. But I have some problems with adding two variables to a constraint. Is there anybody who can help me out.

My current code is as followed:

```
def constraint1(ETa, Qhydro)
   for j in range(0,Numbas):
    for i in range(0,Nummon):
        if (i-(j*Nummon))==0:
            ETa[i+(j*Nummon)+11]-((1-R[j])*S0[j])+S[i+(j*Nummon)]-P[i+(j*Nummon)+11]-Rdown[i+(j*Nummon)]+Qhydro[i+(j*Nummon)]
        else: 
            ETa[i+(j*Nummon)-1]-((1-R[j])*S[i+(j*Nummon)-1])+S[i+(j*Nummon)]-P[i+(j*Nummon)-1]-Rdown[i+(j*Nummon)]+Qhydro[i+(j*Nummon)]
    return ETa, Qhydro
con1=({'type':'eq','fun':constraint1})
```

This gives the following error: TypeError:constraint1() takes exactly 2 arguments 1 given. How to solve this?

I solved the problem as followed.

```
def constraint1(x)
S=x[0:36]
Qhydro=x[36:48]
```

In this way, the constraint has only to return one value and it works :)

Comment: Where are you calling the function "constraint1"?
The error states that you have called the function with only 1 parameter while it should be 2.

Comment: What's your `minimize` call?   Is `ETa` the array your are trying to minimize, and `Qhydro` some static parameter?  Or is `Qhydro` also a minimization variable?

Comment: That's incomplete code and therefore help is hard. Show more of it. Hunch: (1) the signature of ```constraint1``` needs ```args``` in your minimize-call. (2) Futhermore your return-style (tuple) will be trouble too. Read the docs what should be returned (3) Your constraint looks non-smooth (if-else). Not a great idea too.

Comment: ETa and Qhydro are both minimization variables.

Comment: I edited the post in which the solution is added.